# fatal error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory

Tags: glfw

Using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

I have cloned a repo that has nice software in it, however, I can't
find any valid instructions for solving the following issue.
When I try and build the software it sayes.

main.cpp:12:19: fatal error: glfw3.h: No such file or directory

I assume I need to install glfw3, also "locate glfw3" etc. returns nothing. My main.cpp program has this in it "#include "

How do you fix this ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 10):

this may help

```
sudo apt-get install libglfw3 libglfw3-dev
```

and while including

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and the same error. I had previously installed `libglfw3`, and reinstalling did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 7):

```
$ apt-cache search glfw3
libglfw3 - portable library for OpenGL, window and input (libraries)
libglfw3-dev - portable library for OpenGL, window and input (development files)
libglfw3-doc - portable library for OpenGL, window and input (documentation)
```

So, just `apt-get install` it.

This approach shall be standard for any Ubuntu user.

Comment: That fixed it!. Thank you. Thats a cool solution, I've learned somthing new today.

Comment: helpful approach for new users. if only other users mention `apt-cache`.

Comment: Upvote for "teaching the person to fish"